# TYPO3 6.2 required field - image/text

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I want a new required field in TYPO3.
In the content element "image/text" the images can include an altText.
It should be possible, that this field is a required field.

I put this into my exttables.php

```
$TCA['tt_content']['columns']['altText']['config']['eval'] = 'required';
```

It doesn't work for me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the new File Abstraction Layer (FAL) the image references won't be saved in the tt_content table.

The answer is:

```
$TCA['sys_file_reference']['columns']['alternative']['config']['eval'] = 'required';
```